# Building a RealTime Chat System

Tags: rest, websocket, database-design, architecture

WebSockets to have two-way real-time communication. However, I'd like to have a history of all messages, and when the chat application is opened, retrieve the message history. For this history, I could use REST communication.

My question is, what's the best approach:

Resend the entire history via WebSocket when the Chat application is opened, or
When the chat opens, load the history via REST API and then open a WebSocket for real-time messages.

Answer (score 1):

I Think The best approach would be to load the history via REST API when the chat application is opened and then open a WebSocket for real-time messages. This approach allows you to separate the initial loading of the message history, which can be a potentially large amount of data, from the real-time communication via WebSocket, which is more efficient for exchanging small, frequent updates. By using REST for retrieving the message history and WebSocket for real-time messages, you can optimize the communication protocol based on the characteristics of each type of data.